# Is there a PowerShell equivalent for C#'s default operator, and if so what is the syntax?

Tags: powershell

In C#, it's possible to get the default value of any type using the [`default` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default):

```cs
var i = default(int); // i == 0

// in C# 7.1+
int j = default; // j == 0
```

Is there a similar construct in PowerShell, and if so what is it? As far as I've been able to determine in my Googling and testing, `default` is only recognized by PS when present in `switch` blocks.

Comment: `[int]::default` ?

Comment: @iRon: That's the same as `[int]::coffeecup`, in that by default PowerShell allows you to refer to non-existent members without error. Under `Set-StrictMode` this will give an error.

Comment: That said -- `[int]::new()` is accepted, which is probably as close as you can get to `default` for value types. For reference types you'd still have to write `$null` yourself, though. Something like `[int] $null` and `[int] $i = $null` also "happens to work", but this involves PowerShell's own conventions on conversions and I don't know if the results are documented to such an extent that you could say they're the same as `default` in all cases. If you're not looking for the exact semantics but only an equivalent it might do, though.

Comment: The `$null` conversion trick fails in at least the case of enums (where PowerShell demands a valid label). They still accept `::new()`, though. Amusingly, PowerShell allows you to declare an enum with no labels (`enum E {}`) and then refuses conversions!

Comment: PowerShell variables never don't have a value; a variable that has not been assigned a value will be 0 if numeric, or `$null` if a string. The "default" value of an object will be defined by what the parameterless constructor does when called.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately not all value types have a parameterless default constructor (e.g. `DateTimeOffset`).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin How do you create a numeric (or any value-type) variable that is not assigned a value? The only way I can see to create an uninitialized var is via `New-Variable` and that seems to create a var of type object that is thus implicitly set to `$null`.

Comment: Oh, right -- I confused the concept of constructibility with the presence of a default constructor. Value types without a default constructor can always still be instantiated (that's just an IL thing), but of course then not necessarily by calling a constructor... `[Activator]::CreateInstance([DateTimeOffset])` will work, but I don't recommend that as a default approach because it's so slow. If you *really* need the C# equivalent, I suggest just using C#: `Add-Type -TypeDefinition "public class Default<T> { public static T Value; }"` and then `[Default[DateTimeOffset]]::Value` will work.

Comment: @IanKemp - Normally, you don't create variables without assigning them values. I'm having trouble visualizing why one would need this; it's beginning to sound like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); could you clarify why you want this _in PowerShell_?

Comment: For that matter, and perhaps somewhat surprisingly, `New-Object DateTimeOffset` also works flawlessly, even when constructor syntax does not. Both of them do fail on `string`, obviously.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I don't actually have a problem, this is very much a theoretical "how do I do <X I can do in programming language Y> in <programming language Z>" question because I was simply interested to know if my Google-fu was extraordinarily weak, or it just wasn't possible, or I was just being a numpty.

Comment: @IanKemp - While at least superficially, all Turing-complete languages are isomorphic, they're not all created equal, and they don't all target the same set of problems. Before looking to translate a theoretical construct from one language to another, see if the construct actually makes sense in the target language's problem set. PowerShell is targetted to being a _shell_, not a general-purpose programming language; chances are that asking the question 'does this construct make sense in bash/fish/zsh/etc' will give you a valid answer for PowerShell as well.

Comment: @IanKemp - Admittedly, PowerShell can also target problems of the same class that VBScript and ECMAScript do, so the 'bash' question I just mentioned may not _always_ be the best question to ask; depending on the problem, asking about its validity in VBScript or ECMAScript may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has no direct language construct for it because it doesn't need it -- due to its loose typing you are almost never required to produce a value of a specific type and there is no support for creating generic types or functions. Untyped variables start off as `$null` if you do nothing special. Typed variables start off as whatever value you explicitly give them, and that's generally sufficient due to PowerShell's liberal rules for conversion (`[int] ""` and `[int] $null` are both `0`).

Only in rare cases does this fail, like attempting to declare a variable of type `DateTimeOffset`, as there is no default constructor and `$null` or `""` won't convert. Arguably, the fix there is to just explicitly construct a value using whatever the type does offer (`[DateTimeOffset] $d = [DateTimeOffset]::Now`, `[DateTimeOffset] $d = [DateTimeOffset]::MinValue`, `[DateTimeOffset] $d = "0001-01-01 00:00Z"`). Only in the very rare case that you have a dynamic type, and you'd like to get what C# would give you with `default`, would you need some special code. You can do it in pure PowerShell (well, almost, we need to call a method available since .NET 1.0):

```
Function Get-Default([Type] $t) { [Array]::CreateInstance($t, 1)[0] }
```

And then `[DateTimeOffset] $d = Get-Default DateTimeOffset` works (there is no way to infer the type in this case, though you are of course free to omit it from the variable).

Of course this does create a garbage array on every invocation; it does not invoke any constructors of the type itself, however. There are more involved approaches that avoid array creation, but they all involve getting complicated with generic methods (relying on LINQ) or explicitly compiling C# and aren't really worth demonstrating as they're less general. Obviously, even the function above should be used only in the unusual case where it might be needed and not as a general way of initializing variables -- typically you know the type and how to initialize it, or you don't care about the type in the first place.